# TableLayoutPanel row index order is wrong from what is shown?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

First time asking a question here. You have been an amazing help thus far, but this problem really has me stumped!

In my form, I have this structure: [image: Fig: 1, my Table Layout panels]

It consists of 1 TableLayoutPanel with 3 rows (I call this the rowLayoutPanel), each row contains another TableLayoutPanel with a number of columns (I call these the columnLayoutPanels), each of which contain a single GroupBox

I want to get a list of the GroupBoxes in the columnLayoutPanel in a single row of the rowLayoutPanel

To that, I use the a function with this code, giving it the rowLayoutPanel and an integer 'rowPanelRowIndex' which contains the index of the row want in the rowLayoutPanel

```
private List<GroupBox> GetGroupboxesFromRow(TableLayoutPanel rowLayoutPanel, int rowPanelRowIndex)
    {
    List<TableLayoutPanel> columnLayoutPanels = rowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<TableLayoutPanel>().ToList<TableLayoutPanel>();
    List<GroupBox> groupBoxes = columnLayoutPanels[rowPanelRowIndex].Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToList<GroupBox>();
    return groupBoxes;
    }
```

In this instance, I want the middle row, so I call the function as such:

```
List<GroupBox> groupBoxes = GetGroupboxesFromRow(theLayoutPanelInFigure1, 1);
```

But the list I get contain not the groupboxes from index 1, but from index 0, as you can see from this image: [image: Fig 2: The outcome of calling my function with index 1]

This is where it gets weird. I check columnLayoutPanels variable from the function, and find that the indexes do not correspond to what is shown: [image: Fig 3: The apparent contents of index 1, which does not match what is shown as being in index 1 in Fig 1.]

I find the groupboxes I am looking for in index 2: [image: Fig: 4, the groupboxes I am looking for]

Meanwhile, the groupboxes shown in index 2 in Fig 1 is in index 0 of the list.

What am I doing wrong? Changing the height of a rowindex still changes the correct index's height.

Comment: It is iterating the TableLayoutPanel.Controls collection that is getting you into trouble.  You assume that they are ordered the way they are displayed.  Not the case, they displayed in the column order as determined by the TableLayoutPanel.SetColumn() call.

Comment: If this is the case, wouldn't TableLayoutPanel.RowStyles[1].xxx change a different row than the second displayed? It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I circumvented the entire thing using

```
    private List<GroupBox> GetGroupboxesFromRow(TableLayoutPanel rowLayoutPanel, int rowPanelRowIndex)
    {
        TableLayoutPanel columnLayoutPanel = (TableLayoutPanel)rowLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(0, rowPanelRowIndex);
        List<GroupBox> groupBoxes = columnLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().ToList<GroupBox>();
        return groupBoxes;
    }
```

Instead. It works.